# Trying to perform an action whilst a variable is above zero in XNA

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xna, logic

I am creating a basic 2D space shooter game in `XNA 4.0`.

I have a `player` class and in its Update method it calls a `shoot` function if the space bar is pressed. It checks this every frame. In my main `game` class I have a check on whether the player intersects with a ammo boost item. When the player intersects with this item it should set the players bullet delay to 1 (instead of 10) and sets the variable `ammoBoost` to 500 which reduces by 1 every frame.

So now when the player presses space bar it should fire the bullets with only 1 delay for 500 frames.

So far I have everything working and it fires with only the small delay, but I can't get it to reset the bullet delay to 10 when the `ammoBoost` variable has reached 0 after the 500 frames.

I've including relevant code snippets:

main game class

```
// Update boosts and check for collisions
foreach (Boost b in boostList)
{
    b.Update(gameTime);

    if(b.boundingBox.Intersects(p.boundingBox))
    {
        // if life boost 
        if(b.boost == 1)
        {
            // add life to player lives
            hud.playerLives += 1;
            // make boost invisible
            b.isVisible = false;
        }
        // if bullet boost
        else if(b.boost == 2)
        {
            b.isVisible = false;

            // set ammo for gun
            hud.boostAmmo = 500;
            p.boostAmmo = 500;
        }
    }
}
```

player class update method:

```
    // fire bullets
    if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) 
    {
        shoot(boostAmmo); 
    }

    // shoot (used to set starting position of bullets)
    public void shoot(int boostAmmo)
    {


       // if boostammo is above zero boost is active and there should be no delay on bullets firing
if (boostAmmo > 0)
{
    bulletDelay = 1;
    Bullet newBullet = new Bullet(bulletTexture);
    newBullet.position = new Vector2(playerPosition.X + 32 - newBullet.texture.Width / 2, playerPosition.Y + 30);
    if (playSounds)
    {
        sm.playerShootSound.Play();
    }

    newBullet.isVisible = true;

    if (bulletList.Count() < 20)
    {
        bulletList.Add(newBullet);
    }
    boostAmmo = boostAmmo -1;
}
else if (boostAmmo <= 0)
{

    // shoot only if the bullet delay resets
    if (bulletDelay > 0)
    {
        bulletDelay--;
    }

    // if bullet delay is at zero then create a new bullet at player position and make it visible on the screen, then ad that bullet to the list
    if (bulletDelay <= 0)
    {
        Bullet newBullet = new Bullet(bulletTexture);
        newBullet.position = new Vector2(playerPosition.X + 32 - newBullet.texture.Width / 2, playerPosition.Y + 30);
        if (playSounds)
        {
            sm.playerShootSound.Play();
        }

        newBullet.isVisible = true;

        if (bulletList.Count() < 20)
        {
            bulletList.Add(newBullet);
        }
    }

    // reset bullet delay
    if (bulletDelay == 0)
    {
        bulletDelay = 10;
    }
}
```

Why is the bullet delay not reseting back to 10 after the 500 frames have passed?

Comment: Are you actually shooting ammo for 500 frames? You have update logic in your `shoot` method that probably belongs elsewhere. More specifically, your `bulletDelay` variable is getting decremented, but only if a bullet is being shot. Same thing with your `boostAmmo` variable. Instead, those variables should be updated in your `update` method.

Comment: I suppose it is only 500 frames if the spacebar is held down in this case. Otherwise it is whenever the player presses spacebar. This all happens in the Update method.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are doing is setting bulletDelay back to 10 ... repeatedly.
Right now, when boostAmmo <= 0 you set bulletDelay back to 10, then you do some more checks. Then, repeat, you set bulletDelay back to 10. bulletDelay never reaches 0!

Also, you're never firing a bullet if boostAmmo > 0. I'll let you see if you can figure the rest out on your own, but I'll edit this answer if you need me to give you a full solution~

Comment: I updated my question with a more complete version of the `shoot()` method minus resetting bullet delay to 10 at the second if statement. I cant workout why it doesn't reset the bullet delay to 10. It should popout of the first if statement after boost ammo reaches zero. Then pop into the other if statement and set the delay to 10 at the bottom? I'm clearly missing something obvious :)

Comment: My tired and slightly-out-of-practice eyes tell me that you have an IF-ELSE statement, so it completely skips over the ELSE if boostAmmo > 0. But, maybe I shouldn't have tried answering something this late ;n.n you'll want someone else to look at this. However, I "hope" I've pointed you and anyone who wants to help you in the right direction~

Comment: It should be skipping over the else statement if the first if statement is true. It should fire the bullets either normal speed or fast, depending on whether ammoboost is above or below or equal to zero. Thanks though.